# Identify the Player shown in this picture?

Tags: tennis

Identify the Player shown in this photo?
[image]

Comment: Well, all you needed to do was to go to [Google Images](http://images.google.com/), click on [Search by Image](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/images/searchbyimage.html) and put the picture there. (Either input the url, or upload the file from your hard drive, or simply drag and drop.)

Comment: This question is off-topic because this is a [photo finder](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/478/527), a research request.

Answer (score 2):

This player is **Mario Ančić**, a Croatian professional tennis player (now retired).

You can see its description [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_An%C4%8Di%C4%87)